# Keep saved wifi spots when reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: installation, wireless

When I upgrade to 13.04 at the end of this month, I want to preserve all the wifi passwords that I have saved from my workplace/friends houses/etc.  But I don't want to do an 'upgrade' or anything like that, I like to do a fresh install on a reformatted hard drive.

How can I preserve all the saved wifi hotspots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a folder on your filesystem that keeps all the network profiles.
That folder is

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

If you copy that onto a USB stick, you should be able to paste the content of it into the new install's system-connections folder.

Similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/136939/where-are-wireless-profiles-stored-in-ubuntu).

Comment: Now that is the most awesome, unpretentious comment in a long time.

Comment: what comment ..?